# React multi-select selected value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [this](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) component to make a react multi-select. When I use a normal select if works perfectly. I have the following code.

```
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={this.state.selectedOption.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
```

But when I add, `multi={true}` it gives `undefined` in the console. What am I doing wrong? Is there anything else to be added to the attributes?

Plus the value inside the select box doesn't change. Here is an example- https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/94309/

Comment: It's not as much that the value is undefined, but rather that an array doesn't have a property label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would read the docs that you linked to, you would find the following statement [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#multiselect-options)

> The onChange event provides an array of selected options or a comma-separated string of values (eg "1,2,3") if simpleValue is true

So, in your case you have to take an array as input, your `handleChange` would therefor be something like

```
handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
  this.setState({ selectedOptions });
  selectedOptions.forEach( selectedOption => 
    console.log( `Selected: ${selectedOption.label}` ) 
  );
}
```

Your render would then also change to

```
render() {
  return (
    <Select
      name="form-field-name"
      value={this.state.selectedOptions}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      options={[
        { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
        { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

as you want to pass in the values that got selected or `undefined`. If the value would be anything else but the property `value` on your options, you would need to supply the `valueKey` property to your component, but it is set by default on `"value"` so in your case you don't seem to need it.

The props you can find [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#select-props)

A working version can be found here (note that in your fiddle and in your example, the `multi` prop was missing)

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  handleChange(selectedOptions) {
    this.setState({ value: selectedOptions });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={this.state && this.state.value}
        multi={true}
        onChange={(...args) => this.handleChange(...args)}
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.0/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.0.0/dist/react-input-autosize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The main issue is the select box not getting populated. I have updated the question with a fiddle that shows the problem.

Comment: @SoorajChandran I added a working example of the code you provided

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `selectedOption` will be an array in case of `multi={true}`. So of cause `selectedOption.label` will be undefined. But something like `selectedOption[0].label` should work.

Comment: The main issue is the value not getting populated in the select box.

Comment: And the selectedOptions array always has a length 1. Means - only the last selected value is in there.

Comment: Well, I guess that `value` should also be an array in this case. Could you create a codepen for this issue?